# Merging together results from a UNION in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to combine the results of a Union from

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(terms) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT project_num) as total 
FROM projects
WHERE terms >= '2017/01/01' AND Building_designer='SOMEPERSON'
GROUP BY MONTH(terms)
UNION
SELECT MONTHNAME(terms) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT project_num) as total 
FROM archive
WHERE terms >= '2017/01/01' AND Building_designer='SOMEPERSON'
GROUP BY MONTH(terms)
```

I get the following: RESULTS FROM THE SQL STATEMENT

[image: RESULTS FROM THE SQL STATEMENT]

I am trying to make it so the total will be the combination of the multiple instances of the month.
The sql tables are exactly the same.

This Is what I would like it to look like:

[image]

Comment: All the essentials of the question need to appear *in the question itself*, not at external sites.

Comment: It is unclear whether you want the distinct to be across the two tables or just a sum of the distinct values from the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `FULL OUTER JOIN` would be ideal.  But in your case, let's do two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT month, MAX(total_projects) as total_projects, MAX(total_archive) as total_archive
FROM ((SELECT MONTHNAME(terms) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT project_num) as total_projects, 0 as total_archive
       FROM projects
       WHERE terms >= '2017/01/01' AND Building_designer = 'SOMEPERSON'
       GROUP BY MONTH(terms)
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT MONTHNAME(terms) AS month, 0, COUNT(DISTINCT project_num
       FROM archive
       WHERE terms >= '2017/01/01' AND Building_designer = 'SOMEPERSON'
       GROUP BY MONTH(terms)
      )
     ) pa
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month;
```

EDIT:

Oops.  You only want one column.  If you want to count the number of *distinct* projects for each month, then do a `union all` and then combine the results at the next higher level:

```
SELECT month, COUNT(DISTINCT project_num) as total
FROM ((SELECT MONTHNAME(terms) AS month, project_num
       FROM projects
       WHERE terms >= '2017/01/01' AND Building_designer = 'SOMEPERSON'
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT MONTHNAME(terms) AS month, project_num
       FROM archive
       WHERE terms >= '2017/01/01' AND Building_designer = 'SOMEPERSON'
      )
     ) pa
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month;
```

Comment: presumably with quality of data at hand using UNION ALL is safe?

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a sum expression on the entire query.

```
SELECT month, SUM (total) FROM
(SELECT MONTHNAME(terms) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT project_num) as total FROM projects WHERE terms >= '2017/01/01' AND Building_designer='SOMEPERSON' GROUP BY MONTH(terms)
UNION
SELECT MONTHNAME(terms) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT project_num) as total FROM archive WHERE terms >= '2017/01/01' AND Building_designer='SOMEPERSON' GROUP BY MONTH(terms))
GROUP BY month
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick thought would be to just do something like this. You essentially want to sum the counts from each table.

```
select month, sum(total) from 
(
SELECT MONTHNAME(terms) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT project_num) as total FROM projects WHERE terms >= '2017/01/01' AND Building_designer='SOMEPERSON' GROUP BY MONTH(terms)
UNION
SELECT MONTHNAME(terms) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT project_num) as total FROM archive WHERE terms >= '2017/01/01' AND Building_designer='SOMEPERSON' GROUP BY MONTH(terms)
) group by month;
```

Answer (score 0):

transform into a derived table, put an alias then aggregate

```
select 
x.month,
sum(x.total) [Total]
from (
SELECT
  MONTHNAME(terms) AS month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT project_num) AS total
FROM projects
WHERE terms >= '2017/01/01'
AND Building_designer = 'SOMEPERSON'
GROUP BY MONTH(terms)
UNION
SELECT
  MONTHNAME(terms) AS month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT project_num) AS total
FROM archive
WHERE terms >= '2017/01/01'
AND Building_designer = 'SOMEPERSON'
GROUP BY MONTH(terms)
) x

group by x.month
```